# Apache Tika 1.7: Parse files in a zip archive

Tags: java, scala, apache-tika

Using Apache Tika 1.7, how do I recursively parse the files within a zip archive up to some recursion limit?

The recursive part is important since a zip archive might contain another zip archive.

I assume it can be done using the new `RecursiveParserWrapper` but I couldn't find any example online - the Jukka's example [here](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/RecursiveMetadata) uses different interface than the one provided by Tika 1.7

Answer (score 1):

In theory, this should just be a case of pointing you to the [Apache Tika Examples page](http://tika.apache.org/1.7/examples.html), but right now recursion is the [only one still to finish](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1390) for that page. So, I'll have to grab a suitable bit of a unit test for you, and modify it for a limit

Basically though, the key class you need is [EmbeddedDocumentExtractor](http://tika.apache.org/1.7/api/org/apache/tika/extractor/EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.html). You need to provide an implementation of that on your `ParseContext`, and that'll be used to recurse. Normally you could just use [ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor](http://tika.apache.org/1.7/api/org/apache/tika/extractor/ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.html), but since you want limits you need a custom one

Try something like:

```
protected class RecurseWithLimits extends ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor {
   protected static final int MAX_DEPTH = 4;
   private int depth;
   private ParseContext context;
   private RecurseWithLimits child;
   protected RecurseWithLimits() {
      this(0, new ParseContext());
   }
   private RecurseWithLimits(int depth, ParseContext context) {
      super(context);
      this.context = context;
      this.depth = depth;
   }
   @Override
   public void parseEmbedded(
        InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, boolean outputHtml)
        throws SAXException, IOException {
       if (child == null) {
          if (depth >= MAX_DEPTH) {
             // Too deep, skip
             return;
          }
          child = new RecurseWithLimits(depth+1);
          context.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor,child);
       }
       super.parse(stream,handler,metadata,outputHtml);
   }
}

// In main parsing code
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
InputStream inp = TikaInputStream.get(new File("test.zip"));
ContentHandler text = new BodyContentHandler();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
context.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor, new RecurseWithLimits());
parser.parse(inp, new Metadata(), text, context);
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Maybe the API has changed or maybe it was just the specific file type I was working with, but the nested documents were just reusing the EmbeddedDocumentExtractor instance they already had, not getting one from the ParseContext for each new file. I used a ThreadLocal to track depth instead, and that worked fine.